# CSS break child after nth

Tags: html, css

I am trying to break a certain number of elements by half.

For example:

I have a wrapper around many items, and i want to break them in two columns.

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#wrapper {
display: flex;
flex-wrap: wrap;
flex-direction: column;
}

.flex-container {
flex-basis: 75%;
}

.flex-con {
  flex-basis: 25%;
}

#bottom {
    max-width: 100%;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #205BA1;
    display: flex;
    padding: 1rem;
    margin-right: 0 !important;
    flex-wrap: wrap; 
    }
    
    .item:nth-child(5n) {
        page-break-after: always;
    }
```

```html
<div id="bottom">
    <div class="flex-container">
        <div id="wrapper">
            <div class="item">a</div>
            <div class="item">b</div>
            <div class="item">c</div>
            <div class="item">d</div>
            <div class="item">e</div>
            <div class="item">f</div>
            <div class="item">g</div>
            <div class="item">h</div>
            <div class="item">i</div>
            <div class="item">j</div>
            <div class="item">k</div>
            <div class="item">l</div>
         </div>
     </div>
     <div class="flex-con">
         <div>stuff here</div>
     </div>
 </div>
```

I want to break the items based on the count or something like that, so that i have always and only !2! columns of items in the flex-container class- however, the number of items changes each week (+ 1 per week)

I could change the nth-child every week but i want i dont want to do that if it would be possible

```
.item:nth-child(5n) {
    page-break-after: always;
}
```

Ive added an Image to kind of show what i want it to look like
i just want them in two columns inside the first flex-container

```
item a item b
item c item d
item e item f
```

[image: should look like this]
thanks in advance

Comment: If you have flex, use flex: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: im trying to achieve this with flex, however i can't break the items with flex- they just stack in the first row

Comment: *"i want to break them in two rows"* - I see a column, not a row. the word you want is **columns**

Comment: where is the title for each column in your HTML ?

Comment: im sorry, not my native language.. edited the question

Comment: i think u mean the title from the image? the picture is only a rough guide. i have attached a code-snippet that shows how it should look like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use

```
#wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}

.flex-container {
  flex-basis: 75%;
}

.flex-con {
  flex-basis: 25%;
}

#bottom {
  max-width: 100%;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #205BA1;
  display: flex;
  padding: 1rem;
  margin-right: 0 !important;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.item:nth-child(5n) {
  page-break-after: always;
}
```

```html
<div id="bottom">
  <div class="flex-container">
    <div id="wrapper">
      <div class="item">a</div>
      <div class="item">b</div>
      <div class="item">c</div>
      <div class="item">d</div>
      <div class="item">e</div>
      <div class="item">f</div>
      <div class="item">g</div>
      <div class="item">h</div>
      <div class="item">i</div>
      <div class="item">j</div>
      <div class="item">k</div>
      <div class="item">l</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-con">
    <div>stuff here</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: that works like a charm, thank you, much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Look at my codepen, is this what you are looking for?
https://codepen.io/agentbraun/pen/zYKQxGJ

```html
#wrapper {
display: flex;
flex-wrap: wrap;
flex-direction: column;
height: 50px;
  -webkit-columns: 3;
     -moz-columns: 3;
          columns: 3;
  -moz-column-fill: balance;
       column-fill: balance;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code below, achieves the goal as explicitly required in the question, making rendering two columns, that orient from left to right:

```
A B
C D
E F
. .
. .
```

```css
.item{ float: left; width: 50px; }
.item:nth-child(2n + 1){ clear:left }
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="item">a</div>
  <div class="item">b</div>
  <div class="item">c</div>
  <div class="item">d</div>
  <div class="item">e</div>
  <div class="item">f</div>
  <div class="item">g</div>
  <div class="item">h</div>
  <div class="item">i</div>
  <div class="item">j</div>
  <div class="item">k</div>
  <div class="item">l</div>
</div>
```

Comment: i do appreciate your help, altough that didn't quite work with what i had and what i wanted to achieve,@connexo 's answer solved it for me

PS: it may be that it comes through my vague formulation, not a native speaker here

Comment: You probably need to give the `wrapper` element `overflow:hidden` to work with floats like I suggested in my example. I did not make to suggest grid because I view it as a last-resort due to it's high complexity which makes it very tough to understand for most developers